# Add a suffix to duplicates on PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, update

Not sure about the term "undouble", I am just trying to add a unique index on a column but it contains doubloons, so I need to update data first.

Figure this data:

BEFORE update

```
1;foo
2;foo
3;foo
4;bar
5;bar
6;anyother
```

AFTER update

```
1;foo0
2;foo1
3;foo2
4;bar0
5;bar1
6;anyother
```

Note than values without duplicates are unchanged.

My DB is Postgres 9.5.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ROW_NUMBER function to add a suffix to each repeated value.

If you'd rather avoid the first one (mostly for those rows without duplicates):

```
with ct as
(
  select id , row_number() over (partition by data order by id) rn
  from   t
)
update t
set    data = data || case when ct.rn = 1 then '' else (ct.rn-1)::text end
from   ct
where  ct.id = t.id;
```

> ```
> select * from t;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | data
> -: | :---
>  1 | foo 
>  2 | foo1
>  3 | foo2
>  4 | bar 
>  5 | bar1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=c5890cd9bf5785ff49a3b766f14d17c7)*

Comment: Thanks you that sound perfects!

Comment: How may I generate the update from this select?

Comment: I need to update data yes

Comment: wow, what a professionalism.. You won't remember it (you said it on your description), but I will :) gracias amigo

Comment: I'm glad to help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98043/discussion-between-slim-and-mcnets).